# What is the recommended way to clean oil based stain out of a spray gun?

Tags: cleaning, staining, spraying

I would like to know what the proper or recommended way to clean the oil based stain out of my spray gun after use is.

I am using [this stain product](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Sikkens-Translucent-Cetol-SRD-Exterior-Wood-Finish-Butternut-1-Gal-SIK240-072-01/203218741#.UZLhELWsh8F).

I have the following antique spray gun:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a link to the [Power Painter manual(PDF)](http://www.wagnerspraytech.com/portal/download.php?src=portal/downloadcenter/dateien/spraytech/power_painters_manual/Optimus_Sprayers_April_2009/0525800_eng.pdf&system_id=307648&root=358970) on Wagner's site..  Its a newer version but the cleaning instructions will be very similar.

> [image: Cleaning the Container]
>   [image: Cleaning the Suction Set]
>   [image: Cleaning the Components]